# Concatenate an HTML attribute value with Flask data

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

How do I concatenate a value in a Jinja template?  I tried the following but the value is rendered separately from the attribute.

```
<input type="button" id="button" + {{ entry.id }}>
```

Comment: `id="button{{ entry.id }}"`

Answer (score 13):

Look at the output of your current template: `id="button" + 3`.  Anything outside of `{{ }}` isn't interpreted by Jinja, it's just treated as text.

Either put the expression right next to the text, or put the string inside the expression.

```
id="button{{ entry.id }}"
or
id="{{ "button" ~ entry.id }}"
```

The `~` is a special Jinja operator that does concatenation (like `+`), but converts each side to a string first.